# Getting 404 with react router app with nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have a react frontend app that uses react-router to create different routes. On development server its working fine but when I build the project it gives me 404 while accessing it with different routes directly. Website perfectly opens with `xyz.net`. And it gives 404 when I try to access it with `xyz.net/login`.

Here is my nginx conf

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name  xyz.net www.xyz.net;
root /root/frontend/react/build/;
index index.html;


location /api/ {

    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}
```

}

Comment: Probably a duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599233/1397590

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me when I ran into this issue:

```
location / {
                #...
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
                #...  
      }
```

However, I've encountered errors in other projects using `*.ejs` templates for development builds, and `*.html` plugins for production builds with webpack. The answer to which I found here:

[React-router issue when refreshing URLs with SSL Enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439198/react-router-issue-when-refreshing-urls-with-ssl-enabled)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I don't see anything pertaining to linking to internal S/O links as bad practice however (in the link you provided). It seems very common actually, can you point me to a reference where this is clearly stated as a no-no?

Comment: No problem! I appreciate the insight nonetheless. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, and it worked.